# Como capturar determinada parte do conteudo de uma div?

Tags: javascript

Olá tenho uma `div` que tem uma determinada altura e conteúdo

```
<div class='mydiv'>

<p> blabalbalala </p>
<p> blabalbalala </p>
<p> blabalbalala </p>
<p> blabalbalala </p>

</div>
```

Supondo que essa `div` tenha uma `height` de `100px`, como faço para capturar apenas os 30 primeiros px?

Comment: O que você quer fazer exatamente? Você vai usar esses 30px de altura pra que?

Comment: @ErlonCharles quero dividir em outras divs essa div com tamanho 100px

Comment: @Rod E o conteúdo? Não seria melhor trabalhar com um número 'x' de linhas?

Comment: Podes calcular que elemento é interceptado pela linha dos 30px. E esse elemento deve ser includido ou excluido.

Comment: @renan  tenho uma div com 100px, quero capturar os 20 primeirios px e adicionar em um array o conteudo page:[], logo esse array, devem conter 5 itens

Comment: A pergunta é interessante, mas o que todo mundo aqui deve estar estranhando é o motivo de você precisar disso. É bem incomum.

Comment: @bfavaretto é para estilizar essas divs separadas como uma página a4, entretanto eu quero saber como manipular os nodes dessa div do conteúdo

Comment: E se os 30px caírem no meio de um elemento, o que você quer fazer com ele?

Comment: @bfavaretto a ideia é adicionar também com push

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo algumas sugestões dos comentários fiz o código abaixo que itera os elementos filhos e compara a posição em relação ao elemento pai.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('.mydiv'), val = 50, elements = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < div.children.length; i++) {
    if (div.children[i].offsetTop < val) {
      elements.push(div.children[i]);
    } else {
      break;
    }
}
console.log(elements);
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
  <p>blabalbalala</p>
  <p>blabalbalala</p>
  <p>blabalbalala</p>
  <p>blabalbalala</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fica uma sugestão:

```
var els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mydiv p'));

var incluidos = els.filter(function(el){
   return el.getBoundingClientRect().top < 30; 
});

incluidos.forEach(function(el){
   el.classList.add('incluido'); // ou correr outro código com esses elementos
});
```

#### exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/dqba9qen/

Este código cria uma array `incluidos` com todos os elementos `p` cuja posição `.top` é inferior a 30px.